# how to get json Flickr feed images

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to get json data flicker images, but I'm a bit rusty and can't get it start it properly.

Would be nice to have a small help so I can get an better idea.

following snippet:

```js
(function() {

  //changed the callback so that it is defined
  window.cb = function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
      $("<img>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if (i === 3) {
        return false;
      }

    });
    console.log(data);
  }

  var tags = "london";
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=cb&tags=" + tags;
  document.head.appendChild(script);


})();
```

```css
#images {
  height: 185px;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#images img {
  border: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: What you mean by parse?

Comment: @jcubic, probably fetch, and show them into `#images`

Comment: @AdamAzad yes correct.

Comment: You want to do an AJAX query to get the feed and retrieve the data, here you are just loading the feed like it was an external js script file. Does the callback execute? As you seems to be using jQuery this [tutorial](https://viget.com/inspire/pulling-your-flickr-feed-with-jquery) may help and would do it in a cleaner way, a callback on the global scope is a bit messy.

Comment: @GillesC it's not normal script file it's JSONP. and you need to use global callback for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate over data.items and create img tags out of media.m:

```js
(function() {

  //changed the callback so that it is defined
  window.cb = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var $images = $('#images');
    for(var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
      $('<img/>').attr('src', data.items[i].media.m).appendTo($images);
    }
  };

  var tags = "london";
  var script = document.createElement('script');

  script.src = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=cb&tags=" + tags;
  document.head.appendChild(script);


})();
```

```css
#images {
  height: 185px;
  width: 240px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0; overflow: auto;}

#images img {
  border:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: that's great thanks, I'm now able to carry on. really appreciated. @jcubic